# Slower than light photons in vacuum?

Tags: photons, speed-of-light

[This report on the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-glasgow-west-30944584) site suggests that optical photons have been prepared that travel slower than c in vacuum. How is this possible?

Comment: Read about group velocity and phase velocity.

Comment: I'd appreciate if someone explains the whole mechanism here though, seems quite interesting.

Comment: What, phase and group velocity of single photons over path lengths of a metre or more?

Comment: single photons are prepared to travel at speed lower than c..interesting. illumination?

Comment: Read the last part (peloton).
it says.'' the main bunch of riders - may be moving at a constant speed. But within the bunch an individual rider may moving more slowly, dropping back for a rest or a drink."
Meanwhile other riders in the bunch are moving faster to get to the front.

The bunch is a beam of light, travelling at - yes - the speed of light. The riders are photons, travelling at their individual speeds.''
its all about group velocity ,phase velocity ,single velocity..read this
http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath210/kmath210.htm

Comment: Except the article is about single photons, not a light beam

Comment: What you're missing, Dirk, is that there is no "single photon" while in the wavelike behaviour in free space.  The mask is absolutely forcing  the wave from a single **emitted** photon to become a multispectral packet, and the phase vs group velocity rules apply.  This article looks suspiciously like a lot of hullaballoo over nothing.

Comment: Here is the article from which the news report was derived. http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jacquiline_Romero

Comment: Depends. If the delay is time t over 1 metre, and remains constant over n metres, no news. OTOH if the delay = nt, then big news.

Comment: The article is on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.3987

Comment: May I invite everyone here to [submit a complaint to the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/complaints/complain-online/) for their pure sensationalism.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **Paul's** (http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath210/kmath210.htm) source answers it brilliantly. "The main bunch of riders - may be moving at a constant speed. But within the bunch an individual rider may moving more slowly, dropping back for a rest or a drink." Coupled with **Mr. Witthoft's** response "What you're missing, Dirk, is that there is no "single photon" while in the wavelike behaviour in free space. The mask is absolutely forcing the wave from a single emitted photon to become a multispectral packet, and the phase vs group velocity rules apply. This article looks suspiciously like a lot of hullaballoo over nothing." you have your anwser.